# Set .desktop shortcut as default email application

Tags: email, settings

How to set chromes gmail shortcut, or any other app.desktop, as default email client? It does not show up in the settings section for default applications. All i see there are geary and gnome-gmail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your gmail to open all email links in two ways:

**Easy Way**

If you sign in to your gmail account from google chrome, you should see an 'eye' icon that says that the site wants to install a service handler. Click on it and then `allow` and click `done`. Now, whenever you click an email, it will open in your gmail.

**Hard way**

1. Open your favorite text editor and add the following lines to it:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   firefox https://mail.google.com/mail?view=cm&tf=0&to=`echo $1 | sed ‘s/mailto://’
   ```

save it as `open_gmail.sh` (or whatever you like)

2. Type in terminal the following command by giving the exact path of `open_gmail.sh` file:

`chmod u+x /path/to/open_gmail.sh`

3. Now I assuge `thunderbird` is your default client. I will edit `thunderbird.desktop` file in this example. First just back-up that file by:

`cp /usr/share/applications/thunderbird.desktop path/to/where/you/want_to_save`

4. Now open `thunderbird.desktop` by:

`sudo nano /usr/share/applications/thunderbird.desktop`

and find the line that says `Exec=thunderbird %u`

5. and make it look like:

`Exec=/path/to/open_gmail.sh %u`

Save and exit.

6. Run `sudo update-desktop-database`

Now whenever you click an email address, it will open in gmail in firefox. If you are not signed-in to gmail, it will first ask you to sign-in.

If you want to revert this, replace the edited `/usr/share/applications/thunderbird.desktop` with the backup of the original `usr/share/applications/thunderbird.desktop` file.